# TensorFlow incompatible shapes binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a pandas dataframe of features and samples, and a single series with binary category (0 or 1) values. With that I'm trying to train a neural network, but I am getting the error:

```
TensorFlow incompatible shapes binary classification
```

Here is a summary of the code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, series_y, random_state=1, test_size=0.25)

best_weight_path = 'best_weights.hdf5'

x = df_x.to_numpy()
y = series_y.to_numpy()

numpy_x_train = X_train.to_numpy()
numpy_y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
numpy_x_test = X_test.to_numpy()
numpy_y_test = y_test.to_numpy()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=best_weight_path, verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
model.fit(x, y, validation_data=(numpy_x_test, numpy_y_test), callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer], verbose=0, epochs=1000)

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

Shouldn't the last dense layer have 2 units as there are two possible outcomes, so where is the shape `(None, 1)` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the correct choice of an appropriate loss function according to the format of your labels. you have 2 possibilities when using softmax in classification task:

1 possibility: if you have 1D integer encoded target, you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function (**this seems to be your case**)

```
n_class = 2
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

2 possibility: if you have one-hot encoded your target in order to have 2D shape (n_samples, n_class), you can use `categorical_crossentropy`

```
n_class = 2
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)).values

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: @simernes let me know if there are problems

Comment: Would the 2nd possibility allow me to do the following?
    pred = model.predict(numpy_x_test);
    pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1);
    y_compare = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1);
    score = accuracy_score(y_compare, pred);
    
because I now get the error 

    ValueError: `axis` must be fewer than the number of dimensions (1)
    
Please forgive my ignorance, I'm trying to understand keras but I'm struggling a little

Comment: don't worry... why did u choose the 2nd option... from your code it seems to me that you only have to change the loss in  sparse_categorical_crossentropy maintaining the rest as is. np.argmax(..., axis=1) is correct to obtain predicted class from softmax output layer. the latest error say you that you are not passing an array of (n_samples, n_class) to argmax

Comment: @simernes don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer